# Vertical orientation for FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, tabwidget

Can any one please give a code for creating the TabWidget in the vertical orientation . I have to implement the TabHost with android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.
!

Thanks in advance ! Awaiting for response.